# How do you convert date taken from a bash script to milliseconds in a Java program?

Tags: java, bash, datetime

I am writing a piece of code in Java that needs to take a time sent from a bash script and parse the time to milliseconds.  When I check the millisecond conversion on the date everything is correct except for the month I have sent which is January instead of March.

Here is the variable I create in the bash script, which later in the script I pass to the Java program:

```
TIME=`date +%m%d%Y_%H:%M:%S`
```

Here is the Java code which parses the time to milliseconds:

```
String dt = "${scriptstart}";
java.text.SimpleDateFormat scriptStart = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMDDyyyy_HH:mm:ss");
long start = scriptStart.parse(dt).getTime();
```

The goal of this statement is to find the elapsed time between the start of the script and the current system time.

To troubleshoot this I printed out the two:

```
 System Time = 1269898069496 (converted = Mon Mar 29 2010 16:27:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
 Script Start = 03292010_16:27:45
 Script Start in Milli = 1264804065000 (Converted = Fri Jan 29 2010 16:27:45 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time))
```

Comment: Could you just send it the output of `date +%s`?

Comment: Interesting; someone downvoted the question and all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) web site both those timestamps in ms are printing the correctly represented time. The `DD` should be `dd` in your string formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "dd" instead of "DD".  You are using "Day in year" instead of "Day in month".

So change this: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMDDyyyy_HH:mm:ss")`

to this: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy_HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you should be using "MMddyyyy" instead of "MMDDyyyy". "DD" is the day of the *year*, not the day of the *month*.

That apparently causes it to override the month that it already parsed, which in turn causes the output to be January 29 -- the 29th day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

The date command (which is independent of Bash, by the way) will print the time in seconds since the Epoch without having to convert it using Java:

```
scriptstart=$(date +%s)
echo ${scriptstart}     # example: 1269903559
```